# DATE FORMAT SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, resultset

I have a table called Abbonamento that has the following attributes:

```
Abbonamento(idAbbonamento, tipo, DataInizio, DataScadenza, ....)
```

DataInizio and DataScadenza are of type `DATE`.
The problem borns when I do a select on this table:

```
        String queryAbb = "select idabbonamento, tipo, DATE_FORMAT(datainizio,'%d-%m-%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(datascadenza,'%d-%m-%Y'), ...;
                       prest = con.prepareStatement(queryAbb);
        rs = prest.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            a=new Abbonamento();
            a.setIdAbbonamento(rs.getInt(1));
            a.setTipo(rs.getString(2));
            a.setDataInizio(rs.getDate(3));
            System.out.println(rs.getDate(3)); 
            a.setDataScadenza(rs.getDate(4));
            ...
        }
```

Now, if the date DataInizio in the db is for example `2013-11-05 00:00:00` I would like to have `05-11-2013` but the println prints `0004-10-13`.

What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @GaborSch I'm using the DBMS MYSQL...

Comment: [**`DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%d-%m-%Y')` should work fine**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1249e/1). It will give you `05-11-2013`.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal but it doesn't..

Comment: If I do the query in the dbms the result is right while if I print the date from Java it prints another value!

Comment: I suggest that you run your query directly against your db without any application code involved.  If the date format meets your expectations there, it is correct and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: so the problem i in the Java code... but I can't understand where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
rs.getDate(3)
```

you should use

```
rs.getString(3)
```

because the data is already formatted as String. If you want to get as `Date`, first, a Date object is created from your `05-11-2013` string, then you receive that.

If you have `Date` objects in your objects, you should either `parse()` the returnes string *with the same format* you returned from the DB, or *let the JDBC* do the conversion for you (in this case, simply `select idabbonamento, tipo, datainizio, ...`) without formatting.

I recommend that let JDBC do it. Less user code, less trouble :)

```
String queryAbb = "select idabbonamento, tipo, datainizio, datascadenza, ...";
...
a.setDataInizio(rs.getDate(3));
// reading the formatted data:
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat().format(a.getDataInizio());
```

Actually, there is one more trick, but you don't have to care about: `rs.getDate()` returns `java.sql.Date`, but you probably use `java.util.Date`. That's not a problem, because java.sql.Date is a subclass of java.util.Date, so this assignment is totally valid.

Comment: the fact is that the method setDataInizio accept the type Date. I can't pass a String parameter.

Comment: yes, in this way it works but it prints 2013-11-05 instead of 05-11-2013. That's what I'm trying to do with the method date_FORMAT..

Comment: You have problems with *reading* the data as well. I updated the answer how to format `dataInizio` for example, but it really depends on your framework. Maybe in `Abbonamento` class you can introduce a `public String getFormattedDataInizio()` where you can hide the formatting code I just put above.

Comment: That's good, just add another getter that will return the same data, but **formatted**.

Comment: no, I'm using rs.getString(3) now but the date will have the format: yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Again: I think your **real problem** is not the *querying*, but the *displaying*. If you store your dates in `String`, you can solve it with a different formatting in the DB. But if you store your dates in `Date`, your **web framework** must be set up to use that formatting. Try to find out how it could be done. If not working, ask another question.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @GaborSch! for the moment I leave things as they are. When I will finish the web site I will try to manage this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select idabbonamento, tipo, convert(char(10), datainizio, 105)....
```

Answer (score 0):

In a database-independent way, you could use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For example:

```
java.util.Date date = rs.getDate(3);
String dateFormatted = (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat()).format(date);
a.setDataInizio(dateFormatted);
```

Comment: Ok, then you shloud assign it a Date, as you were doing, and, when you need to extract the date, use the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class to format it.

Comment: A `java.util.Date` has no associated format. It is a nummeric representation of a date that needs to be formated in order to convert it to a String